# Найти метод WriteableBitmap.get_Pixels()

Tags: c#

Есть приложение, под WCF или WP (точно не могу сказать). Нужно портировать его под desktop. Не могу найти даже внятного описания (не то что аналога под desktop) одного метода из пространства:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap.get_Pixels()
```

**update**

Узнал точно, это приложение с WP 7.*.
Вот кусок кода, который нужно портировать:

```
Array.Copy(bitmapCache, bitmap.get_Pixels(), bitmapCache.Length);
```

Где:

- bitmapCache - это int[]

Comment: Это, судя по всему, геттер для свойства [`Pixels`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). В десктопной версии его нет. (Моя ссылка на Silverlight, но под WP наверное что-то похожее.)

Comment: Хм, под WP вроде тоже [нету](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx#properties).

Comment: Вот [ещё по теме](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28319945/276994).

Comment: @VladD, немного обновил вопрос.

Comment: @VladD, это метод расширения из стороннего проекта(смотрите мой ответ ниже). За PHP-шное именование методов, Microsoft'овскую команду разработчиков WPF тут-же вздернули бы за что-то неприличное )

Comment: Хм. А не сработает ли для вас [`CopyPixels`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Вопрос в том, какой _смысл_ этого кода? Просто закешировать данные?

Answer (score 1):

Это метод расширения из пространства имен какой-то сторонней сборки, которую в новом проекте почему-то забыли использовать.

В BCL методов с таким стилем именования не было, нет, и к счастью не будет.

Comment: Не совсем то, судя по всему. get_Pixels() представляет из себя int[], а не указатель.

Comment: @z668, ок. В любом случае - это метод расширения из какой-то сборки, которую вы забыли использовать, в отличие от разработчиков изначального проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, аналогом будет

```
bitmap.CopyPixels(bitmapCache, bitmap.BackBufferStride, 0);
```

Но: в старом коде копировалось не больше байт, чем было свободно в `bitmapCache`, а здесь скопируется столько, сколько есть в картинке.

Comment: Все проверю, но к сожалению не сегодня. Завтра отпишусь.

Comment: VladD, необходимо обратное действие. Нужно из bitmapCache (который представляет из себя int[]) заполнить bitmap.

Comment: Задал новый вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424806/int-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-writeablebitmap-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-desktop-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-winforms-wpf