# Int массив в WriteableBitmap для desktop приложения (WinForms\WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Есть `int[]`.

Нужно заполнить `WriteableBitmap` его значениями.

Для Silverlight версии есть свойство [Pixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (как подсказал VladD).

Мне же нужно для desktop (WinForms\WPF).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [`WritePixels`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346816%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
bitmap.WritePixels(
        new Int32Rect(0, 0, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight),
        array,
        bitmap.BackBufferStride,
        0);
```

Comment: Пошло дело. Только в моем случае структуру Int32Rect нельзя оставлять пустой.

Comment: @z668: Исправил. Мне казалось, что пустой Int32Rect означает весь битмап, как [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Для десктопной версии - есть свойство [`WriteableBitmap.BackBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.backbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx)

На время работы с буффером нужно делать `Lock`, после окончания работы - `Unlock`:

[Пример работы с буффером есть в MSDN, в разделе заметок](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// The DrawPixel method updates the WriteableBitmap by using 
// unsafe code to write a pixel into the back buffer. 
static void DrawPixel(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int column = (int)e.GetPosition(i).X;
    int row = (int)e.GetPosition(i).Y;

    // Reserve the back buffer for updates.
    writeableBitmap.Lock();

    unsafe
    {
        // Get a pointer to the back buffer. 
        int pBackBuffer = (int)writeableBitmap.BackBuffer;

        // Find the address of the pixel to draw.
        pBackBuffer += row * writeableBitmap.BackBufferStride;
        pBackBuffer += column * 4;

        // Compute the pixel's color. 
        int color_data = 255 << 16; // R
        color_data |= 128 << 8;   // G
        color_data |= 255 << 0;   // B 

        // Assign the color data to the pixel.
        *((int*) pBackBuffer) = color_data;
    }

    // Specify the area of the bitmap that changed.
    writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(column, row, 1, 1));

    // Release the back buffer and make it available for display.
    writeableBitmap.Unlock();
}
```

Если нужно работать именно как с массивом пикселей, можно попробовать костыль вроде

```
public class PixelWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private WriteableBitmap _bitmap;
    public PixelWrapper(WriteableBitmap bitmap)
    {
        _bitmap = bitmap;
        _bitmap.Lock();
    }

    public int this[int row, int column]
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                int pBackBuffer = GetAddressOf(row, column);
                return *((int*)pBackBuffer);
            }
        }
        set
        {
            unsafe
            {
                int pBackBuffer = GetAddressOf(row, column);
                *((int*)pBackBuffer) = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private unsafe int GetAddressOf(int row, int column)
    {
        int pBackBuffer = (int)_bitmap.BackBuffer;

        // Find the address of the pixel to draw.
        pBackBuffer += row * _bitmap.BackBufferStride;
        pBackBuffer += column * 4;
        return pBackBuffer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _bitmap.Unlock();
    }
}

using (var pixels = new PixelWrapper(bitmap))
{
    pixels[1, 1] = 255;
}
```

Comment: BackBuffer работает с указателем, а не int массивом. Честно сказать не люблю нативные вещи. Если возможно приведите пример кода для конвертации.

Comment: @z668 `WriteableBitmap` - это в принципе нативная вещь. привел пример (из мсдн). `color_data` - `int`. Если нужен ненативный аналог - возьмите обычный `Bitmap`, с `SetPixel`/`GetPixel`. Но он будет медленее.